# PyPDF2 is creating non-alphanumeric characters when reading in pdf's

Tags: python, pdf

I am using the [PyPDF2](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/) package to read in a PDF file. However, when it reads in the PDF file, a lot of non-alphanumeric characters appear that are not present in the original PDF file.

For example, I have lines in the pdf;

PDF (exact copy and paste):

**"The year has actually turned out to be more confusing than expected. But it also leaves me increasingly convinced that a
significant number of cases were false."**

Python (following [this example](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter13/)):

```
import PyPDF2
pdfFileObj = open("file.pdf","rb")
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(1)
pageObj.extractText()
>>> '˝e year has actually turned out to be more confusing than expected. 
 But it also leaves me increasingly convinced that a 
 \nsigni˜cant num˛ber of cases were false.'
```

I understand the "\n" for new line. Thats fine. But why are there characters like **˝** and **˜** and **˛** ?

Is there another argument I need to use with `PyPDF2.PdfFileReader()` to read in the file correctly, without these extra characters?

I know I can use regular expressions to get rid of these special characters later on, but I would prefer to read in the file without them in the first place. This is particularly bad case, because sometimes parts of words are replaced by these special characters; in the example above we see the word  **"The"**  becomes **"˝e"**, which is bad if I want to parse this text and get word counts etc. It would be fine if the special characters just appeared in the place of punctuation, but it doesn't seem to follow that logic - the special characters just appear in random places.

Alternatively, is there another package I could use for python 3.6 that reads in PDF files (textract seems to only be for python 2.x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a sample of the PDF you are parsing it's hard to say why the odd characters are appearing. I've also had problems using PyPDF2 in Python 3.x. I've found [PyMuPDF](http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to be superior for most PDF-related tasks. You could try [extracting text](http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/app2/) with it to see if you have the same characters during text extraction.